# VBS script that zips files errors on empty folders

Tags: vbscript, zip

The following script I found somewhere is zipping a folder:

```
Set Args = Wscript.Arguments
source = Args(0)
target = Args(1)

ArchiveFolder source, target

Sub ArchiveFolder (sFolder, zipFile)

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)
        sFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)

        With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
            .Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items

        Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = _
                 .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count
            WScript.Sleep 1000 
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

However, when trying to zip empty sub-folders.

I receive an error saying:

`Windows was unable to add one or more empty directories...`

I tried adding a condition where if the **sFolder** is empty, skip copying it, but same result.

```
If .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count <> 0 Then
            .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items
        Else
            WScript.Quit
        End If
```

Ideas?

Comment: `.NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count <> 0` would result to true but `sFolder` could _contain_ empty subfolder(s)?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Does .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count refers to subfolders also?